# Interpreting total square error when function values are of many orders of magnitude

Tags: least-squares, error, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit data to and exponential curve. I've done a least-squares fit and come up with an equation of the form $y=ae^{bx}$. The curve looks like a good fit, but I'm wondering about the following:

I have five pieces of data, ranging from $3$ to $3*10^5$. The total square error is $2.6*10^9$ (!!!), but basically all of that is coming from the last data point. Is this necessarily a problem? Or is this just something that happens when fitting a curve to large numbers?

For the curious, my fit is in the graph below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might consider comparing this fit, made to the lowest sum of squared absolute error, to one made with a different fitting target such as the lowest sum of squared relative error. There are times when relative regression can give more desirable results, as might be true here where the dynamic range of the dependent variable is extremely large.